# Only writing 2 rows from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write out only TWO SPECIFIC ROWS from this csv file. Here is my code

```
with open('StudentsMajorsList.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('ComputerScienceStudents.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['StudentID','Major','FirstName','LastName','DisciplinaryAction']

        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')

        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for row in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

in this area

```
 for row in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

I only want to pull TWO ROWS and not all of them. Please help!

Comment: What are your criteria for choosing the rows to keep? You just need to add the logic needed to select them, and call `.writerow()` only on the two rows your want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    if some_condition:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

You haven't told us what `some_condition` is, so we can only guess.